# Issue loading accordian in dialogue box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to display accordian in a dialogue box. It works fine and modal is populated with accordian only for the first time. When modal is opened a second time(after Cancel button is clicked), it has no accordian, only empty data. Below is the code:

$(function() {
  $("#leftButton").click(function() {

```
$('#divPopup').empty();
 $("#divPopup").dialog({
    modal: true,
    minHeight: 400,
    minWidth: 400,
    title: "Modal Dialog",
   open:function(){
     var interfaceCount = "345";
   var sysHeader = '<h3>System Interface Count</h3>';
   $('#details').append(sysHeader); 
   var divsToAppend2 = '<div><div><span>'+ interfaceCount+ '</span></div></div>';
   $('#details').append(divsToAppend2);

    var test =  $( "#details" ).accordion({
         heightStyle: "content",
         collapsible: true
       });

     test.appendTo('#divPopup');

   },
   buttons:{
     Cancel:function(){
       $(this).dialog("close");
     }
   }


  });
```

});
});

I tried with accordian refresh and accordian destroy options, but dint make a difference.
Can anyone help, Thanks.

Sample code: http://jsbin.com/wusolabi/3/edit

I presume issue is since i use $('#divPopup').empty();

Comment: can u try bootstrap accordian?

Comment: Well, your code is not correct, not all `{` have a corresponding `}`.
Try to show a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) example so we can point out anything you are missing.

Comment: I have update my issue with sample. Can you check now